# Use video in the same way as camera in android app

Tags: android, android-camera, android-videoview, android-camera2

My app uses the camera stream to perform some live image classification on the incoming images. For debugging purposes, I'd like to use some prerecorded videos instead.

Does someone know how to use a video in the similar way as the camera, meaning that the video should play continuously while the classifier runs in parallel and always takes the most recent frame (dropping intermediary frames as long as the classification is running).

I just need some high level information how to do it and can figure out the coding myself.

It seems to me that I would need to run the classifier on a background thread that never dies, but rather waits for an input Image -> processes the image -> then posts the results back to the UI-thread for displaying them -> then take the most recent image from the video stream and classify it.

In the camera based version of the app, the above mentioned infinite classification loop is triggered by the cameras `OnImageAvailableListener` and it's `OnImageAvailable` method.

The question is: What is the best way to imitate this behaviour? Using threads, Handlers, Loopers? Or is there some way to put attach a Listener to the Classifier to notify the UI-thread that the image processing has been completed?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57928056/2191652)