# Android: Run image classifier in infinite loop

Tags: android, android-handler

I want to run a image classifier in a infinite loop on a background thread. The function should be called immediately after launching the app. I want to feed the classifier with current frames from a prerecorded video which is simultaneously playing in the UI-thread, so the background thread should tell the UI-thread, once it's done, so I can feed it with the current frame and rerun the classifier.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private VideoView videoView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri uri_video;
    private MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    private MediaController mMediaController;

    private static volatile int currentPosition;
    private static volatile Bitmap mBitmap;

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private volatile boolean runClassifier = false;

    private HandlerThread backgroundThread;
    private Handler backgroundHandler;
    private static final String HANDLE_THREAD_NAME = "ClassifierBackground";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        uri_video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.kim);
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(getApplication(), uri_video);
        videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri_video);
        mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(MyVideoViewPreparedListener);
        videoView.start();

        startBackgroundThread();
    }


    /** Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}. */
    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        backgroundThread = new HandlerThread(HANDLE_THREAD_NAME);
        backgroundThread.start();
        backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());
        synchronized (lock) {
            runClassifier = true;
        }
        backgroundHandler.post(periodicClassify);
    }

    /** Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}. */
    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        backgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            backgroundThread.join();
            backgroundThread = null;
            backgroundHandler = null;
            synchronized (lock) {
                runClassifier = false;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Interrupted when stopping background thread", e);
        }
    }

    private Runnable periodicClassify =
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        if (runClassifier) {
                            //  classifyFrame(); // This will be implemented later
                            Log.d(TAG, "run: Classifier is running");
                            SystemClock.sleep(100); // Instead I simulate the classifier via sleep
                        }
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            setImageViewToCurrentFrame();
                        }
                    });
                    backgroundHandler.post(periodicClassify);
                }
            };


    private void setImageViewToCurrentFrame(){
        currentPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition(); //in millisecond
        mBitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever
                .getFrameAtTime(currentPosition * 1000); //unit in microsecond
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
    }


    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener MyVideoViewPreparedListener =
            new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    long duration = videoView.getDuration(); //in millisecond
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Duration: " + duration + " (ms)",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    setImageViewToCurrentFrame();
                }
            };


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopBackgroundThread();
    }
```

**EDIT1:**
I got some rough idea on how to do it from [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDl4WUKi26WbzLMsM1sXCD4). It seems like I need a backgroundThread (HandlerThread) that has a backgroundHandler (Handler) to communicate with the UI-thread and a Looper to keep the background thread alive. `setImageViewToCurrentFrame` uses `videoView.getCurrentPosition()` to update the `mBitmap`.

However the update is very slow (>10 seconds) compared to the runtime of the classifier (`SystemClock.sleep(100)` which takes 100ms).

**EDIT2:**
The problem seems to be the performance of ImageView which seems to be updated very slowly. Replacing it with TextView, keeps both the background thread and the UI-thread in sync. I will look for other solutions than ImageView now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the gist of my solution. One needs to fit in the actual image classifier at the `SystemClock.sleep` part.
The trick is to use `TextureView` instead of `ImageView` or `VideoView`, since it's faster and more flexible

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_playback);
    initializeBottomSheet();


    uri_video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_demo_video);

    textureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    assert textureView != null;

    startBackgroundThread();
}




/** Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}. */
private void startBackgroundThread() {
    backgroundThread = new HandlerThread(HANDLE_THREAD_NAME);
    backgroundThread.start();
    backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());
    synchronized (lock) {
        runClassifier = true;
    }
    backgroundHandler.post(periodicClassify);
}

/** Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}. */
private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    backgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        backgroundThread.join();
        backgroundThread = null;
        backgroundHandler = null;
        synchronized (lock) {
            runClassifier = false;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Interrupted when stopping background thread", e);
    }
}

private Runnable periodicClassify =
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Get current frame from video playback
                mBitmap = textureView.getBitmap();
                if (classifier != null && mBitmap != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Classifier: Start thread");
                    SystemClock.sleep(3000); // Instead I simulate the classifier via sleep
                }
                backgroundHandler.post(periodicClassify);
            }
        };


@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
    Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri_video);
        mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.start();

                textureView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                        }else{
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopBackgroundThread();
    if(mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    startBackgroundThread();
}
```